# What's golang's equivalent to PHP/Ruby's unpack("C*", . )?

Tags: go

Been searching around, still new to golang, PHP and ruby have an unpack function that unpacks a binary into an array. I'm trying to figure out how to do the following in golang.

```
$test = "\01\00\02\03";
print_r(unpack("C*", $test)); // [1,0,2,3]
```

Or

```
s = "\01\00\02\03"
arr = s.unpack("C*")
p(arr) # [1,0,2,3]
```

What's the best approach to doing this using golang?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note first that your PHP string of `"\01\00\02\03"` is a string consisting of the 4 bytes `\x01`,`\x00`, `\x02`, `\x03` since the `"\01"` are interpreted as octal. See [the documentation for double quoted strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for details.

In Go the syntax `\01` is not correct. As in C an octal sequence is required to have 3 digits, i.e. `\001`. Thus, the PHP string `"\01\00\02\03"` is in Go `"\001\000\002\003"` (which would also work in PHP). With this in mind unpacking is easy and no special function like `unpack` is needed for this:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    s := "\001\000\002\003"
    b := []byte(s)
    fmt.Print(b)
}
```

Output:

```
[1 0 2 3]
```